# GetResponse API contact creation with custom filed php

Tags: php, getresponse

I'm trying to create new contact with custom fields using GetResponse API, here is my code:

```
$headers = [
                    'Accept: application/json',
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'X-Auth-Token: api-key '.$model->getresponse_key
                ];

                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts');
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode([ 'name' => $user->full_name, 'email' => $user->email, 'campaign' => [ 'campaignId' => $model->getresponse_campaign ] , 'customFieldValues' => [['customFieldId' => 'tel', 'value' => [$user->phone]]]], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
                $result = curl_exec($curl);
                $result2 = json_decode($result);
```

I'm getting this response:

```
object(stdClass)#174 (7) {
      ["httpStatus"]=&gt;
      int(400)
      ["code"]=&gt;
      int(1000)
      ["codeDescription"]=&gt;
      string(78) "General error of validation process, more details should be in context section"
      ["message"]=&gt;
      string(34) "Custom field by id: tel not found "
      ["moreInfo"]=&gt;
      string(49) "https://apidocs.getresponse.com/en/v3/errors/1000"
      ["context"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["uuid"]=&gt;
      string(36) "b5a2465b-08df-4cdd-80c8-**********"
    }
```

I really don't know what possibly can go wrong in that code, please help.

Comment: According to the response "Custom field by id: tel not found", maybe a typo? Is it called telephone?

Comment: I made "tel" as a custom field by myself

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use this - 

$response = new GetResponse($access_token);
$campaign = array('campaignId'=>123);
$params = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'campaign' => $campaign,
    'name' => $fname.' '.$lname,
);
$result = $response->**addContact**($params);
$status = $response->http_status;
print_r($status);
```